# Is there anything like preprocessor directives in SQL Server, particularly like #DEFINE?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Whenever I have complicated fields in my `SELECT` my `GROUP BY` ends up looking like a trash fire since `GROUP BY` can't see my aliases defined in `SELECT`. But if there was something like #DEFINE then I could macro that problem away.

Is there anything like that?

Comment: Short answer - no. The use of CTEs might help make things more readable but there is no pre-processor / macro like functionality in tsql. You might find tools/techniques as mentioned by Lukasz - but that is a tool-feature and not a tsql feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is called [SQLCMD Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/edit-sqlcmd-scripts-with-query-editor?view=sql-server-2017):

> `:setvar <var> <value>`

```
:SETVAR DATABASENAME "adventureworks2014"
USE $(DATABASENAME);
```

---

```
:setvar col_list "col1,col2,col3"
SELECT $(col_list), COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM tab
GROUP BY $(col_list);
```

EDIT:

In my opinion the proper way is to use `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT s.col1, s.col2, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT col1 = complex_expression, col2 = complex_expression2) AS s 
            -- the expression is defined once at the same level
GROUP BY s.col1, s.col2;
```

Answer (score 2):

This isn't akin to a preprocessor directive, but one way to clean up the messy GROUP BY statements is to package the complicated SELECT statements into a subquery, and then perform the GROUP BY from an outer query. This helps to clean things up a bit.

For example:

```
SELECT
    dataset.keyvalue,
    SUM(dataset.amt) as total
FROM    
(SELECT
    field1 + field2 + field3 as keyvalue,
    OrderQty as amt
FROM dbo.table1) as dataset
GROUP BY dataset.keyvalue
```

Comment: For the queries where I want to use something like this, adding another nested select further impairs readability. While I understand why order matters for evaluation I don't understand why they don't do a preliminary scan of the script and create an alias index up front. Don't see why aliases have to be tied to evaluation order.

Comment: Or replace the sub-select with a CTE to make it a bit more readable.